# Como puedo vincular una base de datos en Visual Foxpro a un servidor de SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un base de datos en Visual Foxpro y no puedo tenerla como servidor vinculado en SQL Server 2014 ya que el Proveedor de Ole DB de Visual Foxpro es de 32 bits y no se habla con el SQL Server 2014 de 64 bits. Alguien ha logrado vincular el servidor con algún otro proveedor de Ole DB o ha hallado alguna solución?

Comment: Bienvenido. En este sitio esperamos que los usuarios incluyan en el cuerpo de la pregunta algo del contexto y lo buscado e investigado sobre el tema. Te invito a que sigas el [tour] y leas [ask] para aprender lo básico sobre el funcionamiento de este sitio. Aprovecho para compartirte que no recuerdo haber visto nada sobre Visual Fox en este sitio. Ojalá que algún compañero nos pueda dar algo de luz sobre este tema.

Comment: Arthur, no conozco visual foxpro, pero ¿es posible que puedas cambiar la configuración de tu proyecto/solución para generar el proyecto en 32 bits?